# Side-effects in java 8 streams

Tags: java-8, java-stream, side-effects

There are several things in Oracle docs that I cannot fully understand:

```
Operations like forEach and peek are designed for side effects;
```

What they mean by "designed"? What is so special about those two? I can write my code so that any stream API method works via side effect. It's completely up to me, as far as I can understand. What's more, I would usually use peek() to modify the state of the element, not the source itself, which doesn't make it stateful or side-effect-prone.

The javadoc for forEach also says:

```
The behavior of this operation is explicitly nondeterministic.
```

I understand it when they say the same thing about findAny, but what's non-deterministic about forEach? Any operation in parallel stream cannot guarantee ordering if the stream is not ordered. Why is nondeterminism only mentioned for forEach(and finAny, but it means a bit different thing)?

For peek and forEach javadoc also contains:

```
action may be performed at whatever time and in whatever thread the library chooses
```

Again, why only there? Why isn't it mentioned for the rest of the operations?

Comment: Well, your question’s two points actually answer it. For ordinary intermediate operations, the indeterminism is irrelevant, as they should be free of side effects and non-interfering. For `forEach`, wich is “designed for side effects”, the indeterminism matters and must be documented.

Comment: It's only up to you if you want a correct answer.  The specification states clearly that the behavioral parameters passed to most stream methods be _stateless_.  That means that, in the presence of side-effects that might affect the computation, there's no guarantee you get the correct answer.

Comment: So, by "designed for side effects", they do actually mean that there's something in the peek's and forEach's implementation that makes them resilient to side effects, but the rest of the functions cannot guarantee the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, modifying an object state is also a side-effect as the overall state of your program changes after executing your lambda. You can even have a concurrency problem here if you have the same object several times in your parallel stream. Side-effect-free function is a function which does not change the program state and its return value is based only on its arguments. As other stream operations are required to be side-effect-free, it's unnecessary to mention in which thread and at which time they will be executed as this should not matter. But if operation is allowed to have side-effect, this should be mentioned explicitly.

The `forEach` differs from `forEachOrdered` even if the stream is unordered: `forEachOrdered` always guarantees that its lambda is not executed concurrently in several different threads at a time. The `forEach` call not only makes your stream implicitly unordered, but also removes this guarantee: your lambda can be executed concurrently now. And as lambda may produce side-effect, this should be mentioned explicitly.

Comment: "Side-effect-free function is a function which does not change the program state and its return value is based only on its arguments" - 
Isn't this the definition of a pure function ?

No Side effect means: "no mutation of local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or I/O streams" 

A function can be side-effect free, but still have its return value not based on its arguments.

Ex:


int f() {
  return x;
}

This function is side-effect free, but its return value varies with a non-local variable.